# Why does my iMac reboot every day at the same time?

Tags: imac, reboot, restart

Every evening around 10:30, my iMac just stops and restarts. It's not a power outage because another iMac next to it (same plug) is not affected.

I'm thinking maybe a service that's set to run at that time, but I don't see it just shutting down the computer with no warning ..

Answer (score 6):

This is a shot in the dark but worth checking, since it is so specific time wise, have you maybe by accident set up an automatic restart under the `Energy Saver`?

1. Open Preferences
2. Open Engery Saver
3. Click on Schedule

[image: Energy Saver Schedule]

Comment: This was my first thought, too. I'd be surprised if you set this up accidentally, but if OP shares that work/living space with another person, they might be playing a little prank.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Did look this one up, but no dice. Actually, the reboot hasn't happened for some time, and is now much more random. I'm assuming hardware funkiness, and I will call AppleCare ...